# Posting 10 MB GIF file in facebook with Graph API not showing the image on wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, animated-gif

I am posting a 10 MB GIF file to facebook with below API call.

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
    link: url,
    description: "test",
    caption: "test",
    source: url,
    privacy: {
        value: "EVERYONE"
    }
}, function (response) {
    //some code
});
```

The image is getting posted, but in facebook, I cant see the preview image.
But when I click on the image, it is getting opened and playing the GIF.
Can anybody tell me why??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding the GIF image as a video with the following code.

```
FB.api('/me/videos', 'post', {
    file_url: "<url of GIF>",
    description: "<description>",
    caption: "<caption>",
    source: "<url of GIF>",
    privacy: {
        value: "EVERYONE"
    }
}, function (response) { 
    // some code 
});
```

And it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

You can only post GIF images by adding the link to it.
you cannot post a gif animation file.

Comment: Yes, I am adding only UR, but the preview is not correct.